# Current request is not a multipart request error in Hybris

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am pretty new to Hybris and working on a project. As per the requirement, there is an existing working api that accepts a single multipart file along with other params. Now, I need to customize the api to accept multiple files instead of Single file. So in the argument, I replaced the "final MultipartFile mediaFiles" with "final MultipartFile[] mediaFiles". In swagger, now I am able to add the multiple files but when I am executing the api, I am getting the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <errorList>
    <errors>
      <message>Current request is not a multipart request</message>
      <type>MultipartError</type>
    </errors>
  </errorList>
```

I have tried a lot of solutions available on Stackoverflow but till now no luck. My controller method signature looks like below:

```
* @param mediaFile
     * @param bhsItemType
     * @param bhsItemCode
     * @param documentType
     * @return
     */
    @Secured({"ROLE_CSOGROUP","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT","ROLE_PMGROUP","ROLE_DESIGNERGROUP","ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP","ROLE_CESEGROUP"})
    @PostMapping(value = "uploadfile")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    @ApiBaseSiteIdParam
    @ApiOperation(value = "Method to upload media", notes = "Media method handling POST body parameter", produces = "application/json,application/xml", consumes = "application/json,application/xml", authorizations = {
            @Authorization(value = CLIENT_CREDENTIAL_AUTHORIZATION_NAME),
            @Authorization(value = PASSWORD_AUTHORIZATION_NAME) })
    public BHSMediaResponseDTO uploadFile(
            @ApiParam(value = "User Group", required = true) @RequestParam("userGroup") String userGroup,
            @ApiParam(value = "Lead Or Site Code", required = true) @RequestParam("bhsItemCode") String bhsItemCode,
            @ApiParam(value = "BHS Item Type", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "bhsItemType", required = true, defaultValue = "BHSLead") String bhsItemType,
            @ApiParam(value = "BHS Document Type") @RequestParam(value = "documentType", required = false, defaultValue = "OTHERS") String documentType,
            @ApiParam(value = "Media File", required = true) @RequestParam("mediaFile") final MultipartFile[] mediaFile,
            @ApiParam(value = "Media File to be visible to all", required = true) @RequestParam("isPrivate") final Boolean isPrivate,

            final HttpServletRequest httpRequest, final HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
```

**Update**:
I figured out the root cause. I have updated the consumes to "multipart/form-data" but when I send the request, the curl command still shows that the content type is "application/json" and somehow, the content type is getting changed and consumes tag is not getting overridden. Still cannot figure out why.

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code. Pictures of code cannot be quoted.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Thanks for the guidance. I have replaced the images with the code snippets.

Comment: as you indicate the content type gets changed when you use curl. can you add the curl command that you use?